# Does this topology on the dual have a name

Tags: normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space. Let $X^\ast$ denote its continuous dual. It is possible to endow $X^\ast$ with the weak star topology:

Def.1: If $e_x: X^\ast \to \mathbb C$ is the map $\varphi \mapsto \varphi (x)$ then endow $X^\ast$ with the initial topology with respect to $\{e_x\}_{x\in X}$.

Def.2: Denote by $p_{x}: X^\ast \to \mathbb R$ the map $\varphi \mapsto |\varphi(x)|$. Endow $X^\ast$ with the topology induces by these seminorms. As I understand it means the topology with basic open set of the form 
$$U_{\varphi,x,\varepsilon} = \{ \psi \in X^\ast: |\varphi(x)-\psi (x)|<\varepsilon\}$$

Now if instead $X^\ast$ is endowed with the initial topology with respect to $\{p_x\}_{x\in X}$, what sort of topology does one obtain? Does it have a name?

Comment: Wht did you choose $ℂ$ to be the codomain of the $p_x$?

Comment: @k.stm It's a typo, sorry I'll edit the question.

Comment: The initial topology with respect to the $p_x$ is not a terribly interesting topology. It can't distinguish $x$ and $\lambda x$ for $\lvert\lambda\rvert = 1$, for example. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685260/alternative-definition-of-strong-weak-operator-topology) for something similar.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmmmmm.... ok. I will have to think about your comment. For now, could you confirm that my thinking is correct and that this topology in the question is coarser (=weaker) than the weak-star-topology?

Comment: Yes, it is coarser than the weak* topology, and unless $X^\ast = \{0\}$, strictly coarser.