# Equivalence of Definitions of Strong Operator Topology

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I have a couple questions about how we define the strong operator topology on $\mathscr{B} (H)$ that I'm hoping someone can help me with.

First, I thought that the strong operator topology was the initial topology with respect to the family of maps $F_v$, $v\in H$, defined by $T\mapsto \|Tv\|$ (I got this definition from Analysis Now by Pedersen), but I also see online (such as on the wikipedia page for the [strong operator topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_operator_topology)) it being defined as the initial topology with respect to the maps $T\mapsto Tv$. The first implies the second, but I don't see why they would be equivalent?

Second, I'm trying to understand exactly why defining the subbasic open sets of $\mathscr{B} (H)$ as being of the form $$\mathcal{U}_{T_0,v,\epsilon}= \{T\in\mathscr{B}(H):\|Tv-T_0v\|<\epsilon\}$$ gives us the initial topology for the family of maps $F_v$.

I want to show that sets of the above form give us the weakest topology making every $F_v$ continuous, so it seems that the strategy should be to show that, given a basic open subset $B_\epsilon(x)$ of $\mathbb{R}$, $F_v^{-1}(B_\epsilon(x))$ is of the form above, so

$$F_v^{-1}(B_\epsilon(x)) = \{T\in\mathscr{B}(H): |\|Tv\|-x|<\epsilon\} \subseteq \{T\in\mathscr{B}(H): \|Tv-x\|<\epsilon\}$$

However, I don't see how to related this back to sets of the same form as $\mathcal{U}_{T_0,v,\epsilon}$. Would I just pick an operator $T_0$ so that $T_0v=x$? And even then, how can one get equality for the sets?

Many thanks for any help.

EDIT: It's been pointed out that I made a mistake when I said Pedersen defines the SOT as the initial topology given by the maps $F_v$. It actually the topology *induced* by these maps. If that's the case, is it the same as the initial topology defined by the maps $T\mapsto Tv$ like wikipedia says?

Comment: The strong operator topology is not the initial topology with respect to the family $T \mapsto \lVert Tv\rVert$ (unless $H = \{0\}$, in which case there is only one topology on $\mathscr{B}(H) = \{0\}$). These maps cannot distinguish between $T$ and $\lambda\cdot T$ if $\lvert \lambda\rvert = 1$, so this initial topology is [except in the trivial case] not Hausdorff. Pedersen defines the strong operator topology as _the topology induced by the family of seminorms_ $T \mapsto \lVert Tv\rVert$. That's a different construction.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685260/alternative-definition-of-strong-weak-operator-topology) seems closely related.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, okay. So then it doesn't really make sense to ask the second question? Since it isn't the initial topology wrt to those maps? I'm trying to work through a set of notes that as an exercise ask you to show that the topology defined by the sets $U$ (that's how the notes initially define the strong topology), that I described give the weakest topology that make the maps $F_v$ continuous. Does this even make sense to ask then given what you said?

Comment: It makes sense to ask that question. One just needs to adjust the perspective. a) These sets are the open balls with radius $\varepsilon$ and centre $T_0$ for the seminorms $F_v$. So by definition of the topology induced by a family of seminorms, that collection of sets is a subbasis of the topology induced by $\{ F_v : v \in H\}$. b) These sets are the preimages of the balls $B_{\varepsilon}(T_0v)$ under the map $T \mapsto Tv$. Thus they are open in the initial topology with respect to $\{ T\mapsto Tv : v \in H\}$. Hence the topology induced by the seminorms is coarser than the initial …

Comment: topology. Fiddle around a little to see that they are in fact equal.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's so much clearer for me. Thanks, I really appreciate the help.